# Unexplained facebook connect error message "An error occurred with Tip n' Tag. Please try again later"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-oauth

I'm developing a Facebook app for the [web application](http://www.tipntag.com) that I'm working on. I enabled the **Authenticated Referrals** option in the App preferences. However Facebook keeps giving me this error:

> An error occurred with Tip n' Tag. Please try again later.

The problem is the request (bellow) is totally generated by Facebook and I can't figure out why it's not working. However I tried to change the `redirect_url` to be something in website instead of `http://apps.facebook.com/183275271717447/?ref=ts` and it worked fine!

I'm suspecting that it's an internal error in Facebook.

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=183275271717447&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F183275271717447%2F%3Fref%3Dts&response_type=none&display=page&perms=email%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_location&auth_referral=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Just set the application namespace. and this error will not occur!

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are hosting from a different domain than the one you configured with Facebook (e.g. if you test loggin in from localhost instead of www.youdomain.com).